# Substring with inconsistent length

Tags: javascript

I have this quite long string that contains multiple information. So I guess we can say that its a couple of fields concatenated together without any delimiters. I understand that to make this work, all of the lengths of the fields should always be fixed. However, two of the fields represent a name and an amount and no prefixes/suffixes were implemented to maintain a fixed length.

I was wondering how would I got about this problem? Here's a sample of the string and how they should be separated:

**Sample #1**

> **Actual Input:**
>   48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123
>   
> **How it should be separated:**
>   480 | 01 | MCAbastillas | 2200800046300017 | 100518 | 110555 | **130000** | 123

**Sample #2**

> **Actual Input:**
>
>   48004MCAbastillas22008000463000171005181105555000000123
>   
> **How it should be separated:**
>   480 | 04 | MCAbastillas | 2200800046300017 | 100518 | 110555 | **5000000** | 123

In my example only the amount has changed but I'm expecting that the name will vary in length as well. Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: No, I just placed the '|' character just to show how its supposed to be separated. There are no delimiters in the actual string

Comment: So from what you're saying, the name( in your case 'MCAbastillas') and the amount(the highlighted number near the end) are the fields with inconsistent length. If that is the case, and you know that the other fields are ALWAYS gonna be with the same length, you can just check(supposing you start from the left) the first two fields, then you will encounter the name(in case you also know the name cannot contain numbers, you can just check if the string has no numbers in it), then you check the next fixated field by checking the string between the end of the third field and the start of the last.

Comment: If you have any knowledge of who produced this data, a swift slap to the bonce is in order.

Comment: I applied edits to the samples

Comment: @vc73 I also thought of checking if the name has no numbers but apparently, its possible that the name will also contain numbers as there are cases that the name doesn't pertain to a person, but a company name

Comment: Is it only the second to last thing that can vary in length? Can any other parts have different lengths?

Comment: @Sweeper The third field which is the name (`MCAbastillas`) and the second the last field which is an amount (the bolded texts) are the only fields that will vary. The rest are fixed in length

Comment: @Michael I've tried setting up a meeting with them tomorrow to clear things up. But I'm considering the fact that their info won't help me on the technical side which is the problem I have presented here :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use a regular expression for this.

```
String test = "48004MCAbastillas22008000463000171005181105555000000123";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{3})(\\d{2})([A-Za-z]+)(\\d{16})(\\d{6})(\\d{6})(\\d+)(\\d{3})$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if (matcher.matches())
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); ++i)
    {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(i) + " | ");
    }
}
```

Sample output:

> 480 | 04 | MCAbastillas | 2200800046300017 | 100518 | 110555 | 5000000
>   | 123 |

Note that the third and second to last groups do not have fixed lengths.

It's more difficult if the name can contain numbers. My approach would be to run this against the data that you have and print a list of anything that doesn't match (i.e. add an `else` clause). Perhaps then you can come up with a better strategy for handling these cases. For example, something like `([A-Za-z]+\w*[A-Za-z]+)` might be an improvement, because that will at least allow numbers in the middle of the name.

Sometimes you just have to accept that when the data you're given is crap, you just have to do the best that you can and that might mean throwing some of it away.

Comment: I see. I wasn't aware about the `Pattern` and `Matcher` object. I'll definitely try this and tweak it to my needs. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

We want the output

> 480 | 01 | **MCAbastillas** | 2200800046300017 | 100518 | 110555 | **130000**
>   | 123

where the fields 3 and 7 had no fixed length. 
Suppose that we store the string in a string var:

```
String s="48001MCAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123";
```

We can find the fields 1 & 2 easly:

```
System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3)); //has 3 digit
System.out.println(s.substring(3, 5)); //has 2 digit
//we can reduce s
s=s.substring(6); //remove char from 0 to 5 included
```

If you'll call `System.out.println(s);` you well see

> CAbastillas2200800046300017100518110555130000123

Now we have the string... I can deduce that it is composed only by char. So we have to find the first occurrence of  a number... We can use a cycle:

```
int index=-1;

for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) {
    if( Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
        index=i;
        System.out.println("There is a number in the position "+ index);
        break;
    } 
}
```

Now you can extract your name with:

```
 System.out.println(s.substring(0, index));
```

and extract the other 3 fields (you can optimize this part...)

```
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, 16));
    s=s.substring(16); 

    System.out.println(s.substring(0, 6));
    s=s.substring(6); 

    System.out.println(s.substring(0, 6));
    s=s.substring(6);
```

Finally, you can divide the remaining s in two part with length s.length.3 and 3:

```
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length()-3));
    System.out.println(s.substring( s.length()-3,s.length()));
```

Your output will be:

> 480
>
> 01
>
> There is a number in the position 11
>
> CAbastillas
>
> 2200800046300017
>
> 100518
>
> 110555
>
> 130000
>
> 123